# canon LBP 2900B could not print. data transfer to the printer is timed out

Tags: printing

I have LBP 2900B printer of Canon. It has stopped printing. Paper gets rolled over
properly.  but it doesn't print. error it indicates is that 'DATA TRANSFER TO
THE PRINTER IS TIMED OUT.' COULD NOT PRINT.  Please suggest answer to the
problem if possible.  otherwise i am thinking of its replacement by new 
printer.  It is hardly 1 1/2 years old.

Comment: My first steps for troubleshooting would be to do each of the following steps one at the time: check all connections; unplug and replug in the printer; reboot the computer  If that doesn't work, I would reinstall the drivers to see if that helps.

Comment: How is it connected?  USB? WiFi? Cat5?  also add the output of `dmesg | tail --lines=40` just after this happens.